# Increment counter via child components and re-use counter in other child components

Tags: reactjs

**UPDATE** Here is a stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r518n9

I am looking to display groups of questions but number them appropriately so

```
const QuestionLayout = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  return (
    <QuestionGroup count={count} title="Main Questions" />
    <OtherQuestionGroup count={count} title="Other Questions" />
  );
};


const QuestionGroup = ({title, count) => {
  const questions = ["question A", "question B"];

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(questions.length);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <strong>{title}</strong>
      {questions.map((question, idx) => <div>{idx + count}. {question}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}

const OtherQuestionGroup = ({title, count) => {
  const questions = ["question C", "question D"];

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(questions.length);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <strong>{title}</strong>
      {questions.map((question, idx) => <div>{idx + count}. {question}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

*Should* output:

**Main Questions**

1. Question A
2. Question B

**Other Questions**

3. Question C
4. Question D

Instead I get

**Main Questions**

4. Question A
5. Question B

**Other Questions**

4. Question C
5. Question D

It does make sense that my `useEffect` triggers the setState to re-render, I just can't figure out how to prevent it.

Comment: You don't even pass `setCount` and use it inside other components, please share a reproducible example

Comment: And I don't see any difference between output and what you expect... Questions ABCD

Comment: updated to include demo

Comment: A demo that lets us tinker with the code would be preferred. The children components won't have direct access to `setCount` of the `QuestionLayout` component, it would need to be passed as a prop to them. With that though I think you should structure your "question" state in the layout component to more closely resemble how you want them grouped and simply map over the groups, passing each group to `QuestionGroup` with a starting count to increment from when mapping questions.

Comment: derp linked wrong url, here is tinker ready demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r518n9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue with using a single `count` state is that both groups are being rendered at the same time.

```
<QuestionGroup count={count} setCount={setCount} />
<OtherQuestionGroup count={count} setCount={setCount} />
```

They both are passed the initial `count` state of `0` and then both call `setCount` with their `questions` array length. The last group to update state is the state value that is used on the subsequent render, i.e. `OtherQuestionGroup` has an array of length 2, and all groups now are passed the same `count` of `2` value.

What you need is for the layout component to "track" the length of each `questions` array as they are rendered. This is difficult since the arrays are defined in the children.

## Solution Suggestion

You can likely accomplish this without using any `count` state nor `useEffect` to update a `count`. If you can restructure/organize your question data to resemble how you want to render it, i.e. as an array of groups of question arrays then you can easily map over the data.

Given question data restructured

```
const questionData = [
  {
    title: "Main Questions",
    questions: ["A", "B"]
  },
  {
    title: "Other Questions",
    questions: ["C", "D"]
  }
];
```

An updated `QuestionGroup` component to consume a `title`, `questions` array, and initial `count` to increment from.

```
const QuestionGroup = ({ title, questions, count }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <strong>{title}</strong>
      {questions.map((question, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          {idx + count}. Question {question}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then your `QuestionLayout` component maps over the groups and computes the count up to the current group being rendered.

```
const QuestionLayout = ({ questionGroups }) => {
  return questionGroups.map(({ title, questions }, i, groups) => (
    <QuestionGroup
      key={i}
      count={groups.reduce(
        (count, curr, index) => count + (index < i ? curr.questions.length : 0),
        1
      )}
      title={title}
      questions={questions}
    />
  ));
};
```

Render

```
<QuestionLayout questionGroups={questionData} />
```

[image: Edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64691500/increment-counter-via-child-components-and-re-use-counter-in-other-child-compone]

[image] [image]

## Update to your Stackblitz code

https://react-x5sws4.stackblitz.io

1. Store an array of counts in state
2. Create utility to compute total count up to an index
3. Pass total count to index, state update function, and current index to question group components
4. Use a functional state update in the children to update *their* index in the parent state with *their* count

Updated code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [counts, setCounts] = useState([0, 0]);

  const getCount = (arr, toIndex) =>
    arr.reduce((count, curr, index) => count + (index < toIndex ? curr : 0), 1);

  return (
    <div>
      <QuestionGroup
        count={getCount(counts, 0)}
        setCounts={setCounts}
        index={0}
      />
      <OtherQuestionGroup
        count={getCount(counts, 1)}
        setCounts={setCounts}
        index={1}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const QuestionGroup = ({ count, setCounts, index }) => {
  const questions = ["Question A", "Question B"];

  useEffect(() => {
    setCounts(counts =>
      counts.map((_, i) => (i === index ? questions.length : _))
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Questions</h1>
      {questions.map((question, idx) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {count + idx} {question}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const OtherQuestionGroup = ({ count, setCounts, index }) => {
  const questions = ["Question C", "Question D"];

  useEffect(() => {
    setCounts(counts =>
      counts.map((_, i) => (i === index ? questions.length : _))
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Other Questions</h1>
      {questions.map((question, idx) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {count + idx} {question}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks for this. This is very thorough and I appreciate it! My only requirement that I am struggling with to maintain is that the questions live within each component so the child component has to broadcast back to the parent what questions it rendered. Thoughts?

Comment: @DonBoots I do actually. You posted your updated link after I was most of the way through this implementation. I'll tinker a bit more and see what I come up with.

Comment: @DonBoots Updated my answer with updates from your stackblitz. Would something like that work for you?

Comment: I think this could work! Either way, the effort is a great look into React lifecycle and what not. Very helpful!